# Create array to pass same arguments to different classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, switch-statement, arguments

According the match of a switch-statement, my code calls one class or another. Every class takes the exact same group of arguments:

```
switch (propAlarma.asunto[iteracionAlarma]) {
    case "Reinicio Mirth":
        resultado = ReiniciosMirth.main(
            prop,
            propAlarma,
            dt,
            iteracionAlarma,
            propAlarma.json[iteracionAlarma],
            idNotify
        );
        break;
    case "Alerta de actualizacion Mirth":
        resultado = ActualizacionMensajeriaMirth.main(
            prop,
            propAlarma,
            dt,
            iteracionAlarma,
            propAlarma.json[iteracionAlarma],
            idNotify
        );
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("No hay match en el switch");
}
```

These are the classes of the objects I'm passing. E.g:

```
public static String main(
    Properties prop,
    PropiedadesAlarma PropiedadesAlarma,
    DateTime dt,
    int iteracionAlarma,
    JSONObject mailJson,
    int idNotify
) {
```

I'd like to optimize this since I'm planning to add more cases to the switch. I'm new at Java (I'm used to program in Python). In Python I'd do something like this:

```
arguments = [
    prop,
    propAlarma,
    dt,
    iteracionAlarma,
    propAlarma.json[iteracionAlarma],
    idNotify
]

if propAlarma.asunto[iteracionAlarma] == "Reinicio Mirth":
    ReiniciosMirth.main(arguments)
if propAlarma.asunto[iteracionAlarma] == "Alerta de actualizacion Mirth":
    ActualizacionMensajeriaMirth.main(arguments)
```

Comment: If you're new to Java, maybe you should learn about what's called interfaces and dependencies injection...expecially if all your class accepts the same number (and type) of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a common interface for all of these classes that has a `main` method:

```
public interface OptionForTheSwitchStatement { // please give it a better name
    String main(
        Properties prop,
        PropiedadesAlarma PropiedadesAlarma,
        DateTime dt,
        int iteracionAlarma,
        JSONObject mailJson,
        int idNotify
    );
}
```

Then, make all those classes implement `OptionForTheSwitchStatement`:

```
public class ReiniciosMirth implement OptionForTheSwitchStatement {
    public String main(
        Properties prop,
        PropiedadesAlarma PropiedadesAlarma,
        DateTime dt,
        int iteracionAlarma,
        JSONObject mailJson,
        int idNotify
    ) { ... }
}
```

Note that `main` has to be non-static if you implement `OptionForTheSwitchStatement`. If you don't want to change it, that's fine too. See below.

Then, in your switch statement, you can do this:

```
OptionForTheSwitchStatement option = switch (propAlarma.asunto[iteracionAlarma]) {
    case "Reinicio Mirth" -> new ReiniciosMirth();
    case "Alerta de actualizacion Mirth" -> new ActualizacionMensajeriaMirth();
    default -> {
        System.out.println("No hay match en el switch");
        yield null;
    }
};
```

You can think of this as the switch choosing which class' `main` method to call.

If you don't want to change `main` method to non-static, you can use method references instead:

```
OptionForTheSwitchStatement option = switch (propAlarma.asunto[iteracionAlarma]) {
    case "Reinicio Mirth" -> ReiniciosMirth::main;
    case "Alerta de actualizacion Mirth" -> ActualizacionMensajeriaMirth::main;
    default -> {
        System.out.println("No hay match en el switch");
        yield null;
    }
};
```

After that, call `options.main` with the arguments:

```
if (options != null) {
    options.main(
        prop,
        propAlarma,
        dt,
        iteracionAlarma,
        propAlarma.json[iteracionAlarma],
        idNotify
    );
}
```